# Access Service Management REST API from Cloud Service using Windows Azure

Tags: c#, azure, service-management

I need to access Windows Azure Service Management REST API directly from the deployed Cloud Service instance. To do that I need to access X509 certificate, right? When I deploy a cloud service, the service management certificate is not deployed to the instance. At least I could not find any certificate in the deployed Virtual Machine (certmgr.msc).

How shall I deploy the X509 certificate to the Cloud Service instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl/#step1). These are for SSL certificate with private key, but are 1:1 for a public key only certificate. This way you will have access to the certificate in all your Instances.

Comment: @Oldrich Svec, just remember to upload the private key of the management certificate, not the public one.  You'll likely need to export your management certificate that's sitting in your certificate store with private key included.